# Apache Extras Cassandra-JDBC: Invalid method name: 'prepare_cql_query'

Tags: jdbc, cassandra, thrift, cassandra-jdbc

I'm using the Apache Extras project cassandra-jdbc ( http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/ ) on version 1.1.1 along with the cassandra-thrift and cassandra-clientutil dependencies on version 1.1.1.

My Cassandra version is 1.0.10 though. I had to use the cassandra-jdbc on version 1.1.1 because the PreparedStatements were not available in earlier versions.

The problem I'm getting is:

```
org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Invalid method name: 'prepare_cql_query'
at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:108)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_prepare_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1438)
```

I read somewhere else ( https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-13577 ) this might be solved by upgrading Cassandra to 1.1.0, but I'm using DataStax so I'm not sure I can upgrade it. Is there another way to get past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is for the simple reason that prepared statements are not supported until Cassandra 1.1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2475

Comment: thanks, looks like I don't have much choice here but to upgrade or try something else.